# In node.js, data I'm sending to stdin only reaches the process once I call end(). What to do if I want to keep writing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, buffer

If I do this:

```
child = child_process.spawn('./resources/backend-exe', {stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'ignore']});
child.stdin.write("Test\n");
```

The child process doesn't react, as if nothing was sent to it. However, if I do this (add one line):

```
child = child_process.spawn('./resources/backend-exe', {stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'ignore']});
child.stdin.write("Test\n");
child.stdin.end();
```

It reacts to the data as normal and sends a response to stdout. However, it means that I no longer can write to the stream. What if I want to write several times? How to "flush" the data without closing the stream?

Here's the entire code of the child process (Haskell):

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = do
  line <- getLine
  putStrLn line
  main
```

Comment: @JonasWilms node streams have no flush method

Comment: @Turtlefight stdin is not a Stream though. It's a Socket. `.flush()` doesn't exist on Sockets though .. :/

Comment: @JonasWilms yeah, but sockets implement the Writable / Readable streams, so the api should be the same

Comment: [`Socket#setNoDelay`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setnodelay_nodelay) looks promising

Comment: @JonasWilms shouldn't make a difference, streams get automatically flushed. Probably the child process isn't working in some way - [small example](https://repl.it/repls/AquaJitteryVisitors)

Comment: The child process is working correctly when I just run it from the console. It accepts the stdin and outputs stdout as intended.

Comment: @user2649762 what exactly is your child process? can you share the code where you read from stdin?

Comment: @user2649762 if you use `stdio: ['pipe', 'inherit', 'inherit']`, can you see the output of the child process?

Comment: Added the code of the child process to the question

Comment: What does `getLine`do? Maybe it expects another line terminator?

Comment: No, it accepts a line until \n. It works as expected when launched from the console.

Comment: @Turtlefight Huh, no, setting stdout to 'inherit' makes child.stdout equal null, and I can no longer read it. Huh, why would that be the case?

Comment: @user2649762 'inherit' basically passes down the `process.stdout` handle to the child process, so the child process can directly write to its parent processes stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `.write()` the data will be automatically flushed after some time.
(You can provide a callback to `.write()` or listen for the `drain` event if you want to know when the flush happended )

e.g:

```
child.stdin.write("Test\n", () => console.log("FLUSHED!"));
```

Here's a working example of ping-ponging between two processes: [repl.it console](https://repl.it/repls/AquaJitteryVisitors)

If you want to process the output of your child process, pass `pipe` to stdio and listen for `data` on stdout:

```
const child_process = require('child_process');

child = child_process.spawn('./program', {stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'ignore']});

// listen for messages from our child
child.stdout.on('data', chunk => {
  console.log("Child sent line: " + chunk.toString());
});

// send a message to the child
child.stdin.write("Test\n");
```

(see [repl.it console](https://repl.it/repls/CoralRottenDisks) for a full example)

Edit:
Your problem seems to be buffering-related.
Haskell will check if your program is running in a `tty`-context, i.e. the program is directly attached to a console, and set is buffering strategy accordingly.

If you launch your haskell program from the console, haskell will use LineBuffering.
However if you call it in a non-tty context it will use block buffering.
You can reset the buffering strategy by calling

```
hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering
```

with either `LineBuffering` or `NoBuffering` to get the haskell process to respond to each line again.

Comment: My child process is basically the same thing - read a line, send it back to stdout.
What could possibly make the difference between end()ing and not end()ing the socket?

Comment: The 'drain' callback activates immediately, as if the line has actually been written

Comment: @user2649762 your problem might be caused from buffering in the haskell process. try calling `hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering` & `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering` before reading from stdin

Comment: @user2649762 np :)  you also could use `LineBuffering`, since you use newlines as separator